# How do I fix my wireless network connection? It stopped searching for wireless connections

Tags: 10.10, wireless, troubleshooting, connection

I am running Ubuntu 10.10
It used to be able to connect and find wireless connections, but now it has stopped completely and doesn't display my home wifi network.
How do I fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Little more information would be great. Are you able to connect to Network manager applet from the panel ? Are you able to create a new connection ? Also please confirm that wireless enble/disable toggle switch on keyboard (if there is one) not disabled wireless

Comment: This question appears to be abandonded, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

This is such an annoying problem... especially if you arent that smart with computers BUT this always seem to get it working for me http://howtofixstuff.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-fix-wireless-connection.html